# Single client for every Pub/Sub subscription?

Tags: redis

Does it makes sense to have many listeners on same channel from **same** client? Is this anti-pattern? Or should I open new client for each sub/socket? Connection limits make me nervous..

---

#### High level overview:

Message from Redis Pub/Sub are sent to all subscribed clients via WS connection.

```js
Redis Pub/Sub -> NodeJS(WebSockets) -> Client
```

---

#### Minimal example:

Notice how I start subsciption client only once outside of WS connection function.

```js
const sub = startRedisForSubscriptions();
const pub = startRedisForOtherCommands();

// new user connects - perfect place to add all behaviour
websocketServer.on('connection', (socket, request) => {
  // subscribe to Redis channels
  sub.subscribe('chat', 'etc');

  // handle messages from subscribed channels
  sub.on('message', (channel, message) => {
    // send to client via WS
    socket.send(JSON.stringify({channel, message}));
  });

  // handle messages from WS client
  socket.on('message', message => {
    const msg = JSON.parse(message);
    pub.publish('chat', {from: ms.from, message: msg.message});
  });
});
```